# Debugger goes to allocator.h instead of to method body when stepping into

Tags: c++, oop, googletest

The following piece of test code is causing me trouble. It compiles ok and tests are passed, but when debugging and trying to step into function AddPizza in line (*) or (**) , it takes me to `allocator.h`  to line  `allocator() throw() { }` and then it continues below. So it doesn't take me inside the method to inspect if everything is all right. This doesn't happen for instance with the previous line with the method `AddIngredient`.   What is going on, is there something wrong with my implementation of  `AddPizza` or some other method that is causing this behavior?
By the way I am using Qtcreator on Windows 10.

```
    TEST(TestPizzeria, TestPizza)
      {
        Pizzeria pizzeria;
    
        try
        {
          pizzeria.AddIngredient("Tomato", "Red berry of the plant Solanum lycopersicum", 2);
          pizzeria.AddIngredient("Mozzarella", "Traditionally southern Italian cheese", 3);
    
          pizzeria.AddPizza("Margherita", vector<string> { "Tomato", "Mozzarella" });//(*)steping into it takes me to allocator.h  to line  `allocator() throw() { }` and then it continues below
          pizzeria.AddPizza("Marinara", vector<string> { "Tomato" });
        }
        catch (const exception& exception)
        {
          FAIL();
        }
    
        try
        {
          pizzeria.AddPizza("Margherita", vector<string> { "Tomato", "Mozzarella" });// (**)also here
          FAIL(); 
        }
        catch (const exception& exception)
        {
          EXPECT_THAT(std::string(exception.what()), Eq("Pizza already inserted"));
        }
}
```

I report here both AddPizza and AddIngredient methods and all necessary methods just in case:

```
    class Ingredient {
public:
  string Name;
  int Price;
  string Description;};

  class Pizza {
      vector<Ingredient> ingredients;
    public:
      string Name; 
      void AddIngredient(const Ingredient& ingredient){ingredients.push_back(ingredient);}
  };


class Pizzeria {
    map<string, Ingredient> mapNameToIngredient;
    map<string, Pizza> mapNameToPizza;
    
    void AddPizza(const string &name, const vector<string> &ingredients)
        {
            if(mapNameToPizza.find(name) != mapNameToPizza.end())
            {
                throw runtime_error("Pizza already inserted");
            }
            else
            {
                Pizza pizza;
                pizza.Name = name;
                vector<string> ingredientss = ingredients;
                for(vector<string>::iterator it = ingredientss.begin(); it != ingredientss.end(); it++)
                {
                    Ingredient ingredient;
                    ingredient = FindIngredient(*it); 
                    pizza.AddIngredient(ingredient);
                }
                mapNameToPizza[name] = pizza;
            }
        }
    
        void AddIngredient(const string &name, const string &description, const int &price)
            {
                if(mapNameToIngredient.find(name) != mapNameToIngredient.end())
                {
                   throw runtime_error("Ingredient already inserted");
                }
                else
                {
                   Ingredient ingredient;
                   ingredient.Name = name;
                   ingredient.Price = price;
                   ingredient.Description = description;                  
                   mapNameToIngredient[name] = ingredient;
                }
            }
const Ingredient &FindIngredient(const string &name) const
{
    auto it = mapNameToIngredient.find(name);
    if(it != mapNameToIngredient.end())
    {
       return it->second;
    }
    else
    {
       throw runtime_error("Ingredient not found");
    }
}
};
```

Comment: There are several function calls on the first marked line. One is to allocate space for the vector, another to construct the vector, and a third to call `AddPizza`. You can also set a breakpoint on the first line of `AddPizza` so your debugger will stop when it is called.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Setting a breakpoint on the first line of AddPizza worked, thanks!  This had never happened to me, why doesn't step into work ?

Comment: Some IDEs have an option to "step into my code" or "step into all code" which includes system libraries etc.. If your ide has those options, you can try to enable the first mode again by default.

Answer (score 1):

GTest use macros and global variables heavily, it's the logic of the GTest framework itself, if you try debugging with step-in, you will most likely enter the assist code other than your test code.

So it's recommended to add a breakpoint in the first line of  `TEST` body, as @1201ProgramAlarm mentioned in the comment.

You can use `g++ -E` to see the code after preprocessing of the original c++ code:

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(foo, bar) { ASSERT_EQ(true, true); }
```

Even for this one-line test, we get one `73533` lines file after preprocessing. I have extracted the tail part and removed some file name and line number information, then we get code snippet as below(It may be different from yours since the compiler and GTest version may be different)

```cpp
static_assert(sizeof("foo") > 1, "test_suite_name must not be empty");
static_assert(sizeof("bar") > 1, "test_name must not be empty");
class foo_bar_Test : public ::testing::Test {
 public:
  foo_bar_Test() {}

 private:
  virtual void TestBody();
  static ::testing::TestInfo* const test_info_ __attribute__((unused));
  foo_bar_Test(foo_bar_Test const&) = delete;
  void operator=(foo_bar_Test const&) = delete;
};
::testing::TestInfo* const foo_bar_Test ::test_info_ =
    ::testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(
        "foo", "bar", nullptr, nullptr,
        ::testing::internal::CodeLocation("a.cpp", 3),
        (::testing::internal::GetTestTypeId()),
        ::testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<
            ::testing::Test>::GetSetUpCaseOrSuite("a.cpp", 3),
        ::testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<
            ::testing::Test>::GetTearDownCaseOrSuite("a.cpp", 3),
        new ::testing::internal::TestFactoryImpl<foo_bar_Test>);
void foo_bar_Test ::TestBody() {
  switch (0)
  case 0:
  default:
    if (const ::testing::AssertionResult gtest_ar =
            (::testing::internal::EqHelper::Compare("true", "true", true,
                                                    true)))
      ;
    else
      return ::testing::internal::AssertHelper(
                 ::testing::TestPartResult::kFatalFailure, "a.cpp", 3,
                 gtest_ar.failure_message()) = ::testing::Message();
}
```

We can see that a class is defined by the `TEST` macro and a global variable is defined, so a direct step in may goes into GTest's internal code or generated code from GTest's macro.